# How to enforce in JavaScript using eslint not to use myStr = myStr + 'Some string'

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

How to enforce in JavaScript using ESLint not to use `myStr = myStr + 'Some string'` and use `myStr += 'Some string'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [operator-assignment](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/operator-assignment) rule:

```
/*eslint operator-assignment: ["error", "always"]*/

x = x + y;
// The above line will throw a linting error

x += y;
// The above line will not throw a linting error
```

(keep in mind, this will apply to *all* forms of operator assignment, like `*` and `-` etc, not just `+`)